# Почему нельзя использовать переменную из класса для генератора списков

Tags: python-3.8

```
class Test:
    a = 5
    b = [a for _ in range(5)]
```

Этот код выдает ошибку

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

якобы переменной не существует